# Parametric plot showing an unwanted boundary at the maximum parameter value

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, filling

I'm trying to fill a parametric plot, but I get this ugly seam for some values of $a$. Observe the following code:

```
f[t_, r_, a_] := {r*Cos[2 Pi*t]*Sin[Pi*t + 2*Pi*a], 
   r*Sin[4 Pi*t - 2*Pi*a]*Cos[2*Pi*t + 2*Pi*a]};
ff[a_] := 
  ParametricPlot[f[t, r, a], {t, -1, 1}, {r, 0.5, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 60];
ff[0.1]
```

[image]

As you can see, there's this ugly seam that appears, and it only appears for certain values of $a$ (not all)! I don't know what's causing it, but given that I'm trying to export it as an animation, this seam is not acceptable. The problem is that I don't know how to get rid of it.

How can I change my code to prevent the seam from appearing?

Comment: add the option `BoundaryStyle -> None`?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1847758).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) comments you can use [`BoundaryStyle -> None`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryStyle.html) to avoid drawing the boundary line entirely.  Then if desired you can draw lines with more control using [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html):

```
f[t_, r_, a_] := {r*Cos[2 Pi*t]*Sin[Pi*t + 2*Pi*a], 
   r*Sin[4 Pi*t - 2*Pi*a]*Cos[2*Pi*t + 2*Pi*a]};

ff[a_] := ParametricPlot[f[t, r, a], {t, -1, 1}, {r, 0.5, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
   PlotPoints -> 60,
   BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[3], Red],
   Mesh -> {0, {0.5, 1}}];

ff[0.1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Mr.Wizard's provides a good solution. but I strongly reccomend replacing

```
MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[3], Red]
```

with

```
MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, rColor, Opacity[1]]
```

where

```
rColor = RGBColor[0.775, 0.820, 0.900];
```

which closely matches the bluish color Mathematica uses fill regions.

However, you might also consider an alternative solution which is somewhat simpler. It doesn't suppress the boundaries lines, it just colors them to blend-in with the region fill color. To my eyes this solves your problem as well as Mr.Wizard's solution does. But my eyes aren't so good, so I leave for you to decide.

```
rColor = RGBColor[0.775, 0.820, 0.900];
ff[a_] :=
  ParametricPlot[f[t, r, a], {t, -1, 1}, {r, 0.5, 1},
    PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
    Axes -> False,
    Frame -> False,
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thin, rColor, Opacity[1]]]
```

I evaluated

```
manip = Manipulate[ff[a], {a, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}];
Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "ff.gif"}], manip]
```

to make the following animated GIF which looks OK to me.

[image: animation]

Comment: I don't think I understand this answer; isn't the fill color just `ColorData[97, 1]` with reduced opacity?  And if one doesn't want to see the boundary at all isn't `BoundaryStyle -> None` sufficient?

Comment: p.s. Merry Christmas!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. 1) You are likely right about the color, but comes as news to me. The RGB color I give doesn't set alpha channel to a lower value, so it can't be quite the same. 2) No, that won't work. Try it. The very thinest sections of region disappear if neither boundary lines nor mesh lines are plotted. 3) A merry xmas and happy and prosperous new year to you.